# Adding simple gui to my simple python code

Tags: python, user-interface

I've written this python code and I'm trying to add a simple GUI. I would like to  use the GUI to get inputs from the user instead of hard-coding the inputs.

```
 import math

def main():
    ciphertext = 'litrutisfgsofnaeeieoitdt'
    myKey = 4

    plaintext = decryption(myKey, ciphertext)
    print(plaintext)

def decryption(key, message):

    colNum = math.ceil(len(message) / key)
    rowNum = key
    shadeNum = (colNum * rowNum) - len(message)
    plaintext = [''] * colNum

    col = 0
    row = 0

    for symbol in message:
        plaintext[col] += symbol
        col += 1 

        if (col == colNum) or (col == colNum - 1 and row >= rowNum - shadeNum):
            col = 0
            row += 1

    return ''.join(plaintext)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want get cipher-text and key from user input and add a button which will do the decryption part and show result in a label. I'm trying to add GUI with Tkinter but to be honest i have no idea how to link it. Any ideas how should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to link it"? It's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with sample code to link your decrypt function with decrypt button in the UI.
Logic is to attach a callback function to the button.

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *


def decrypt(key, cyphertext):
    # do decryption
    return "Decrypted "+key+cyphertext


def callback(cyphertextEntry, keyEntry, output):
    cyphertext = cyphertextEntry.get()
    key = keyEntry.get()
    decrypted = decrypt(key, cyphertext)
    output.set(decrypted)


top = Tkinter.Tk()
frame1 = Frame(top)
frame1.pack()
frame2 = Frame(top)
frame2.pack()
frame3 = Frame(top)
frame3.pack()
frame4 = Frame(top)
frame4.pack()
L1 = Label(frame1, text="Cypher")
L1.pack(side=LEFT)
E1 = Entry(frame1, bd=5)
E1.pack(side=LEFT)
L2 = Label(frame2, text="Key")
L2.pack(side=LEFT)
E2 = Entry(frame2, bd=5)
E2.pack(side=LEFT)
B1 = Tkinter.Button(frame3, text="Decrypt", command=lambda: callback(E1, E2, v)) 
B1.pack()
L2 = Label(frame4, text="Output")
L2.pack()
v = StringVar()
L3 = Label(frame4, textvariable=v)
L3.pack(side=LEFT)

top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need dynamic input, use the raw_input() function (just input() for python 3). If you really need a GUI, I can only point you to the built-in Tkinter module, being probably the simplest (of many) GUI frameworks for python. It's documentation can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html . There would be no point for me to write the complete code for you. It is easy to learn, and if you get stuck, ask a more precise question and someone will sure be glad to answer it.